# resolve a name for internal ip

Tags: networking, lan, webserver

I have searched for an answer and nothing seems to fit right.

Here is what im looking at:

Local LAN setup with both wireless and wired connections, any number of different users/operating systems/devices (PC,Mac and Smart Phones). On the local LAN will sit a XAMPP web server and local site. What I would like is everytime ANY user types in a name (lets just say for example: mysite) into their web browser and hits go it gets redirected to the local web page. I need for all other traffic to go out of the router and through DNS as per normal, just if a specific name is entered go to the local site.

On my windows computer i can do this simply by typing in the local computers share name (eg: My-PC), however this doesn't work on smart phones at all. I can type in the local IP address on any device but I want something a bit more easy.

I don't want to have to run a local DNS just to get one name sent to a local PC and changing all users HOST files isn't going to work (esp since smart phones don't give that option). Also anything that needs vital changes to the router such as installing new firmware is out as well.

I have looked through the router and it doesn't have an option to redirect a internal request, it does for an inbound one (dah) but nothing going out.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you use a squid proxy or similar ?

Comment: @Sirex - No I do not, just a normal router that is port forwarded to the PC running XAMPP on port 80. Im thinking I might just add to a domain name I have an extra bit and redirect it but that seems a bit overkill

Comment: Editing hosts files is not valid for you only due to the smartphone issue? I have multiple IP assignments on my network, and I use to prefer that method, combined with DHCP Reservation on the router. And I have succeeded doing it to my Android and iPhone devices; I think I have the detailed method noted over here. I even use "Kulilin" for the configured computer name and "Kulilin-" for the hosts input name (even when the IP is the same: it is useful for me in case of testing or failing something).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't catch the router you are using but if it's a Linksys you can install ddwrt and configure dnsmasq. It will do exactly what you need.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_-_DNS_for_your_local_network_-_HOWTO

Comment: thanx for your answer, I looked into that and my router isn't compatible, plus i also want this to be repeatable so have updated my question to include no router firmware changes :)

Comment: Ddwrt is great and super flexible. Sorry the router you have doesnt support it. My only other suggestion would be a virtual lightweight Linux vm and setup a dns. Good luck!